# read and write of excel in phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

i accomplished the read of excel with php but the write i cannot, i not know why..
in the file to read, take one column and write in a new file excel and paste there is.. for now only that..
Thank to all..

```
 <?php
     require_once "excel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";
     require_once "excel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mb_http_output('UTF-8');
    set_time_limit ( 0 );
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Desea comenzar el proceso ?

        <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" name="submit">
    </form>



    <?php



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $objPHPExcel_load = new PHPExcel();
        $PHPExcel_save = new PHPExcel();
        $PHPExcel_save->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");
        $PHPExcel_save->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Cedula');
        $PHPExcel_save->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
        $PHPExcel_save->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $inputFileName = 'discussdesk.xlsx';
        $objPHPExcel_load = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel_load->getActiveSheet();
        $cantidad = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();// tamaño de los registros
        $objeto_pegar = $PHPExcel_save->getActiveSheet(0);
        echo "cantidad : ".$cantidad;
        $prueba = true;
        $row = 2;
        $column = 1;
        for($i = 1;$i <= $cantidad;$i++){
            $celda = trim($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue());
            $PHPExcel_save->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $celda);  

            echo $celda.'<br>'; 
            if(is_null($celda)){
                break;
            }
            $row +=1;
        }
        $PHPExcel_save->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

        // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel_save, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');


    }


    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$PHPExcel_writer = new PHPExcel();
    $objReader =  PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007'); // crea el archivo a leer
    $PHPExcel_ = $objReader->load('testFile.xlsx'); // load the file
    $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0) 
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'field1')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'field2')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'field3')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'field4')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'field5')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'field6'); // write the first row(tittle)


    //$PHPExcel_writer->setActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //
    $objPHPExcel_load = new PHPExcel();
    $inputFileName = 'discussdesk.xlsx';
    $objPHPExcel_load = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel_load->getActiveSheet();
    $cantidad = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();// size of row*/


    //echo "count : ".$cantidad;

    //$row = 2;
    //$column = 1;
    //$PHPExcel_writer->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    //$PHPExcel_writer->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, "prueba");  

    for($i = 1;$i <= 1000;$i++){ ?>
        <script> envia_barra(<? echo $i; ?>);

              </script>
        <?php
        /*$celda = trim($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row+3)->getValue());
        $data = file_get_contents("youweb?param=".$celda);
        set_time_limit(5);
        $PHPExcel_->getActiveSheetIndex(0);
        if(preg_match('|<td width="180" class="tblbgcolort"><strong>Departamento:</strong></td>\s+<td width="400" class="tblbgcolort">(.*?)</td>|is' , $data , $dep )){
            preg_match('|<td width="180" class="tblbgcolort"><strong>Departamento:</strong></td>\s+<td width="400" class="tblbgcolort">(.*?)</td>|is' , $data , $dep );
            preg_match('|<td class="tblbgcolor"><strong>Municipio:</strong></td>\s+<td class="tblbgcolor">(.*?)</td>|is' , $data , $mun ); 
            preg_match('%<strong>Puesto:</strong>.+?<td>(.+?)</td>%si',$data,$puesto);
            preg_match("%<div style='float:left;'>(.*?)<\/div>%si", $data , $dir );
            preg_match('|<td class="tblbgcolor"><strong>Mesa</strong></td>\s+<td class="tblbgcolor">(.*?)</td>|is' , $data , $mes ); 
            $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$row, $celda);
            $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,$row,$dep[1]);
            $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2,$row,$mun[1]);
            $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3,$row,$puesto[1]);
            $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4,$row,$dir[1]);
            $PHPExcel_->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5,$row,$mes[1]);

        }else{
            $PHPExcel_->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$row,$celda);
            $PHPExcel_->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1,$row ,"No hay registro");
        }
        $row++;
        if(is_null($celda)){
            break;
        }
    }
    //$PHPExcel_writer->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel_, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('testFile.xlsx');
    //$objWriter->save('php://output');
    //header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"discussdesk.xlsx\"");
    //header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    //$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel_writer, 'Excel2007');
    //$objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```